# Tensorflow 2.0 - tf.estimator.DNNClassifier training for big datasets

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to train a DNNClassifier

```py
    labels = ['BENIGN', 'Syn', 'UDPLag', 'UDP', 'LDAP', 'MSSQL', 'NetBIOS', 'WebDDoS']

    # Build a DNN
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[30, 10],
    n_classes=len(labels),
    label_vocabulary=labels)

    def input_fn(features, labels, training=True, batch_size=32):
       '''
       An input function for training or evaluating
       '''
       # Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
       dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
       # Shuffle and repeat if you are in training mode.
       if training:
          dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()
       return dataset.batch(batch_size)

    # Train the model
    classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train_features, train_label, training=True),
    steps=5000)
```

The training works fine until a bigger dataset is used

```
train_features.shape
>>> (15891114, 20)
train_label.shape
>>> (15891114,)
```

I'm using Google Colaboratory and my session crashes for exceeding RAM use (12GB of RAM) as soon as the training starts

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python

/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1666: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer dnn is casting an input tensor from dtype float64 to the layer's dtype of float32, which is new behavior in TensorFlow 2.  The layer has dtype float32 because it's dtype defaults to floatx.

If you intended to run this layer in float32, you can safely ignore this warning. If in doubt, this warning is likely only an issue if you are porting a TensorFlow 1.X model to TensorFlow 2.

To change all layers to have dtype float64 by default, call `tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')`. To change just this layer, pass dtype='float64' to the layer constructor. If you are the author of this layer, you can disable autocasting by passing autocast=False to the base Layer constructor.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adagrad.py:106: calling Constant.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
```

Before the training starts only 1GB of RAM is used, but as soon as the training starts RAM is rapidly saturated.

---

I'm making it work by providing `chunks` of the dataframe to train/evaluate the model.

Still, it is not clear to me why the RAM is saturated when I provide the whole dataframe for training or evaluation of the `Estimator`.

Comment: Hi ! could you give us a minimal reproducible example so that we can just copy paste the code and try it ourselves. Even better if you can just share the google colab you are using.

Comment: Hi, I've added a link to the notebook and to the dataset I'm using

Comment: Super ! if by any chance you could add the data directly in the colab it would help as well. If it's too much don't worry.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, I don't know any other way but uploading the dataset to your own drive access it from it... Am I wrong?

Comment: No no I was just being lazy and asking you to change the paths to the folder, but it's ok I'll do it myself.

Comment: I have ran the colab notebook, and just before the training, I have added one prediction step:

```python
output = classifier.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train_features, train_label, training=True))
next(output)
```

With this single step, you can see that the RAM is already failing. I will look a bit more in detail in that.

Comment: Yes, the issue is how `input_fn` builds the dataset from the dataframe. I used as a reference this page https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/premade

Comment: I am not sure because you can see that if you build the dataset outside the input function and iterate over it there is no problem of exploding RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I made a copy of your Google Colab and copied the data files in My Drive and trained the estimator, your code just worked: :s [image]. I could train the DNN no problem:

I checked that I was using the big dataset: 
[image]

I did have an `out of RAM` message when I recalculated some of the jupyter notebook cells, but never when I did 'restart kernel', and then after that `Run all cells`. Maybe the problem is with jupyter? Try writing your code in .py file (which you place in drive), and then run it from the colab notebook using `subprocess`, maybe that fixes your issue.